# can't get python command in anaconda test drive to work

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Anaconda using defaults.(i'd post a .png  of button i pushed but i don't have the rep for more than two links)

I am following the test drive for Anaconda [Test Drive](https://conda.io/docs/test-drive.html#managing-conda) and had a problem with Section #2 - Environments.
Following the provided code I created several environments, switched between them, and then deactivated one.
When i deactivated the environment I went to place where 'conda' is not longer a recognized command.

[Anaconda Terminal Session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeMzV.png):
i open anaconda terminal and begin in the root directory.
i successfully activate the environment 'snowflakes'.
i issue command 'deactivate' which should return me to root directory.
however, i am now farther up the file structure where 'conda' is not a recognized command. i suppose i can issue 'cd appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2' to solve the problem but i'm thinking i've probably messed something up and would like to fix the problem.

any suggestions what to do?

some things i encountered before posting question:
1. when i installed anaconda there was a checkbox that had something to do with PATH - but anaconda encouraged me NOT to check the box - so i did not.
2. I have also read some posts here discussing that one should have a simple path so I wonder if I should install this someplace other than the default path - which is kinda long as you can see in the terminal session.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know why the command `conda` is not being recognized.
When you typed the first time (in your screenshot of the terminal) you were at `C:\Users\RAdams.GNSMEM\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2`. Inside this folder you should have the executable `conda`, so when you called it inside this folder makes sense that it may be executed. However, when you called `conda` outside of this folder (the second time in your screenshot) you had no executable file named `conda` to be executed. If you wanted to call the command  `conda` without the need of being in the `Anaconda2` folder, you should have made this command be inside your `PATH` variable. Probably that's what the install manager asked you to do and you refused (maybe it recommended you against it because you're dealing with Windows and it may be somewhat different from what happens in Linux).

**EDIT:**

After taking another look at your screenshot, I saw that the `C:\Users\RAdams.GNSMEM\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2` was, in fact, your environment. You activated this environment and was in the folder `C:\Users\RAdams.GNSMEM`. Being in this environment makes you able to call the executable files within it even when outside of it. The thing is that you activated `snowflakes` (and I think that the other environment was automatically deactivated) after that and then deactivated it. So you had no environments loaded when you called `conda` the last time. Your environments are pretty OK, I guess.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. 

from the test drive document, i was expecting to be in the root environment after issuing the 'deactivate' command, in a place where 'conda' is still usable. that 'conda' is not usable after issuing 'deactivate' is the source of my confusion.

Comment: Glad that I could help!

Comment: @RichardAdams, if the problem was solved, would you kindly mark this as the right answer?

Comment: sure - thank for replying

i'm not sure it is solved though - at least not in a way i understand. 

BTW i'm on my home computer now so the path is a little shorter.

when in the root environment my command line shows (c:\users\richard\anaconda2) c:\users\richard


when i change to another environment - say bunnies - my command line shows
(bunnies) c:\users\richard


if i deactivate bunnies my command line shows
c:\users\richard not 
(c:\users\richard\anaconda2) c:\users\richard

Comment: Yeah, that is expected. When you are in the **root** environment and then activate another, this last one deactivates the former. So when you activate **bunnies** you are deactivating the **root**. Since you only have **bunnies** loaded, if you deactivate it, you'll end with no environments loaded. To be in **root** environment again just activate it like you did before.

Comment: Oh - so rather than deactivate bunnies to return to root, activate root instead? Cool - thanks